# Error on page 2 of Vinogradov's Elements of number theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I just bought a beautiful hardcover copy of I.M. Vinogradov's Elements of number theory. It's a  reprint of the $1954$ edition which was translated from the $5^{th}$ edition.

Now, Vinogradov was a great mathematician, and I find it impossible that he would make a mistake. I also find it hard to believe that the same error is done several times (in the statement of the theorem, in the $3^{rd}$ example following). At first, I thought maybe the symbols were different, but on page 41 they do use "less or equal", and not simply "less than".

Now, am I crazy? Is there really an error on the second page of such a classic? Is that error in the $5^{th}$ Russian edition?
If $50 = 10q + r$, then I can choose $q =4$ which gives me $r=10$ which is equal to $10$, or $q=5$ then $r=0$ which is equal to $0$, so there isn't a single representation of that number if we require $0 \lt r \lt b$.

[image: page 2]

---

Page 2 above, 41 bellow
[image: page 41]

Comment: Sorry to answer in the comments, but this is obviously a typographical error in the book, it should be $0\leq r$ of course, and some of your images even confirm that, since you have $r=0$.

Comment: Thank you Suzu, I also think it is a typo. But on page 2? I wish someone had the Russian edition to confirm.

Comment: They didn't have latex back in those days, so errors could easily occur when the book was being typeset, which the author might easily fail to notice, despite their mathematical achievements.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose $q=4$ then $r=10$ that is equal to $b$, we need to have $r$ strictly less than $b$

Comment: I thought the question was about $0<r$?

Comment: Suzu is right, so what do you choose? r can't be 0 or 10, according to the statement.

Comment: I dindt notice the $0<r$. Yes, $0\leq r$